# Correlation name 'N' not found

Tags: triggers, sqlanywhere

I made this trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER "isok" AFTER INSERT
ORDER 1 ON "dba"."orderz"
REFERENCING NEW AS N
FOR EACH STATEMENT
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO comments (order_id,user_id,com_content) VALUES (N.order_id,1,'OK');
END
```

and SQL Anywhere didn't show an error when I saved it but it does now when I want to insert something into the `orderz` table:

> Correlation name 'N' not found

My code is probably wrong but I searched triggers and I have no idea how to fix the problem. All I want to do is to create a new row in the `comments` table with the new order's `ID` in it.

Could someone tell me how to write an expression that would cover it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace

```
FOR EACH STATEMENT
```

with

```
FOR EACH ROW
```

If you use `STATEMENT` then there is no row to be referenced, because the trigger will fire only once even if you insert ten rows at once.

Comment: Thanks, that really helps :) Perhaps you know a page I could visit for more clear information about triggers? As I don't speak English very well, many of them are really confusing for me.

Comment: @Maciej First, from reading your question and comment I think that your grasp of the English language is good enough. Second, apart from the Sybase SQL Anywhere manual I am not aware of any good resource targeting this specific DBMS: [http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbusage/ptitct.html](http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbusage/ptitct.html)

Comment: You may want to try http://sqlanywhere-forum.sybase.com/ which is a Q&A site (run by SAP-Sybase) dedicated to SQL Anywhere.